# Error:(26, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.harikrishna.myapp4;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText ed1,ed2;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}
public void fun(View V){
    if(V.getId()==R.id.button){
        Editable e=ed1.getText();
        String s=e.toString();
        s=s.trim();
        if(s.length()>0){
            ed2=setText(s);
            ed1=setText("");
            ed2=requestFocus();
        }
    }
    else{
        String s=ed2.getText().toString().trim();
        if(s.length()>0){
            ed1=setText(s);
            ed2=setText("");
            ed1=requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
}
```

compiler shows error Error:(26, 21) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String) and cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String).

pl could u pl some one let me know how to solve this problem

Comment: What should the ed1=setSetText(s) and ed2=setText("") do? Probably use a . instead of the = character

Comment: @Harikrishna did you see and tried my answer??

Answer (score 1):

```
  change your code from 

          ed2=setText(s);
          ed1=setText("");
          ed1=requestFocus();
  to this
          ed2.setText(s);
          ed1.setText("");
          ed1.requestFocus();
```